# How to programmatically add indications to window file's icon

Tags: windows, winapi, icons

I am sorry, but I couldn't come up with a better title. it is probably why I can't find anything about this.
I wanted to know how to make change to windows files icon in code.
for example: like source control show little indications on the bottom right of the icon for being checked in/out, or like backup software shows the file's backup status the same way, or simply like the shortcut indication on the icon.

Comment: If you mean programaticaly set file icon overlays, you need to register Shell extension implementing several Shell interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement a **Shell Icon Overlay Handler**, which is a COM object that implements the [`IShellIconOverlayIdentifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761265.aspx) interface.  Refer to MSDN for more details:

[Creating Shell Extension Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144067.aspx)

[How to Implement Icon Overlay Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127442.aspx)

[How to Register Icon Overlay Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127455.aspx)